# lemon tree water sprout

Tags: citrus

I have a lemon tree grown from seed that is about 2 1/2 years old. I thought from what I read that a very large branch growing from the base area was a water sprout(it grew faster, although it was about 5 and 1/2 feet tall it didn't have even one single branch growing on it, and the leaves were super huge in comparison to the other leaves on the tree). I cut it off at the base and since doing this the health of the tree has gone downhill. I see one tiny new branch forming (very slowly) near the base but other than that there hasn't been any new growth other than this. my question is do citrus trees grown from seed even get water sprouts or can anyone think of another reason it isn't doing well since being cut?

Comment: A picture would help